# How to think of $k$th covariant derivatives in coodinates

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, normed-spaces, tensors

On a Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$ one can simply define the $C^k$ norm of a tensor $T$ as the norm of $\nabla \ldots \nabla T $ with respect to $g$. I am trying to think of $\nabla^{k} T$ in terms of a normal coordinate system. Suppose that $T = T^{i_1, \ldots, i_n}_{j1, \ldots, j_m} \frac{\partial }{\partial x_{i_1}} \otimes \ldots \otimes \frac{\partial }{\partial x_{i_n}} \otimes dx^{j_1} \otimes dx^{j_m}$. what should the $k$th covariant derivative of it look like in a normal local coordinate system?

Comment: I assume you know the coordinate formula for the 1st covariant derivative of a tensor field? You can iterate this to get a formula for the higher derivatives. It gets messy very quickly if you want to write down the exact expression, but the general form (a sum of contractions of various partial derivatives of $T$ and partial derivatives of the Christoffel symbols) should be apparent.

Comment: Additionally, if you choose normal coordinates centered at the point of interest, then all the terms involving Christoffel symbols will vanish at that point (but only at that point).

Comment: So basically for normal coordinates, we just get partial derivatives of the coefficients? Is there any way to make that precise?

Comment: @koch: At the point of interest, we have $\nabla_{\partial_i} {\partial_j} = 0$ and $\nabla_{\partial_i} dx^j = 0$ for all $i,j$ so if you apply the product rule for the covariant derivative on $T$, you will be left only with the partial derivatives of the components.

Comment: To be honest I think Anthony's comment had nicely summarized the situation: there is no nice formula for $\nabla^k T$ when $k\ge 2$, even using the normal coordinates.